# timeDifference(DateTime) is ambiguous for the type DateTime in OpenNTF Domino API

Tags: java, datetime, xpages, lotus-domino

I am implementing OpenNTF ODA in my XPages application but I get the warning "The method timeDifference(DateTime) is ambiguous for the type DateTime" when I change the object type for a DateTime object from the lotus.domino,datetime into the org.openntf.domino.datetime

```
DateTime dtBackToApproval;
dtBackToApproval = currDoc.getFirstItem("Approval").getDateTimeValue();
if (doc.getLastModified().timeDifference(dtBackToApproval) > 10)
```

Anyone has suggestion how I should convert this code?

Thank you in advance!